# View state error if page holds mandatory fields along with attacments

Tags: visualforce

I created a VF page which contains input fields with logic of adding multiple Attachments and the page has some mandatory fields to be entered. When i attach an Attachment without entering the mandatory values, the page is giving View state error instead of showing the errors at mandatory fields.

Can i know how can i handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the attachment to clear the memory it hold in view state.

```
i_objAttachment = new Attachment();
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'The file name should be 27 character long or less.'));
```

Another way to clear the memory is setting the attachment body to NULL.

```
i_objAttachment.Body = NULL;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: if i initialize it then when it holds value also it becomes null

Comment: Unfortunately yes. User need to upload the Attachment again. This is the only way to get around the View State error in Visualforce page with Attachments.